# use function to filled an array in number. if the array is full, then the number will be filled on the second array

Tags: c++, arrays

I working on a program store registered student id in array called registered. and then if that array is full then it will automatically store the student id in another array called waitlist. this action will be done with a function.
I wont be able to make my computer to store the student id into waitlist array when my registered array is full. i am only can use the specific function to stored student id into both array. i also need to print list of student id that is registered and in waitlist by using the same function.
I don't know what to do, i could not find a good tutorial and book is not even helpful at all. Thank you.

here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int maxCap = 10;
void showOption();
void addToRear(int arr[], int& howMany, int value);
void printArray(int arr[], int howMany);
bool isFull(int capacity, int howMany); 
bool isEmpty(int howMany);

int main()
{
    bool repeat = false;
    bool repeatOption = false;

    int reg[maxCap];
    int waitlist[maxCap];
    int option, value, capacity;
    int howMany = 0;
    int registered = 0;
    int waitlisted = 0;
    do
    {
        showOption();

        cout << "please enter your option: 1 ~ 5 " << endl;
        cin >> option;


        switch (option)
        {
        case 1:
            if(isEmpty(capacity, howMany) == true)
            addToRear(reg, howMany, maxCap);
            if(isFull(capacity, howMany) == true)
            addToRear(waitlist, howMany, maxCap);
            break;
        case 3:
            printArray(reg, howMany);
            break;
        case 4:
            printArray(waitlist, howMany);
            break;

        case 5:
            cout << "thank you for using this program. " << endl;

            return 0;
            break;

        default:
            cout << "thank you for using this program. " << endl;
            break;
        }

        //cout << "there are " << howMany << " registered student in this class. " << endl;

        cout << "back to main menu? enter 1 for yes:      " << endl;
        cin >> repeatOption;
    }while(repeatOption);

}

void showOption()
{
    cout << "Main Menu: " << endl;
    cout << "1) Register Student. " << endl;
    cout << "2) Unregister Student. " << endl;
    cout << "3) Print list of registered student. " << endl;
    cout << "4) Print list of waitlisted student. " << endl;
    cout << "5) Exit. " << endl;
    cout << " " << endl;
}
//void getID(int& value)

//enter student id and store it in array register and waitlist
void addToRear(int arr[], int& howMany, int value)
{
    cout << "there are only " << maxCap << " spot for student to be registered." << endl;
    cout << "if there are " << maxCap << " students registered in this class, " << endl;
    cout << "then the rest of the student will be put on waitlist. " << endl;
    cout << " " << endl;
    cout << "enter student ID. " << endl;
    cout << "enter negative value to stop. " << endl;

    int id;
    cin >> id;

    while((id >= 0) && (howMany < maxCap))
    {
        arr[howMany] = id;
        howMany++; 
        cin >> id;
    }


}

//print list of student that is registered or waitlisted
void printArray(int arr[], int howMany)
{
    cout << "there are " << howMany << " number of student in registered list. " << endl;
    cout << "the student ID number is " << endl;

    for (int index = 0; index < howMany; index++)
    {
        cout << arr[index];
        cout << " " << endl;
    }
}

bool isFull(int capacity, int howMany)
{
/if((capacity < 1) || (howMany > 9))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

bool isEmpty(int capacity, int howMany)
{
    if((capacity > 9) || (howMany < 1))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing..??

Comment: try to use function void addtorear to store number in array call register. the array only have 10 index. if the register array is full, then use the same function to store number in another array call waitlist.

Comment: im using a partially filled array. and supposed that i keep entering number to be store in register array, when it reach the limit, then the program should store the number in another array called waitlist. however, when it reach the limit, it will automatically stop asking user to enter number, and back to main menu.

Answer (score 0):

1. It would be easier to have a single array that has both registered and wait listed candidates.
2. While adding you just have to have an end index. So as long as the index is less than your cutoff number your candidate is registered.
3. While deleting you have to move the list up one space after the one candidate entry deleted. This way the registered list will automatically be updated to reduce the waitlisted candidate by 1.
4. Printing you have to check the index if it is greater than cutoff you have both registered and wait list.

Comment: that is the problem. i cant use single array. here is the requirement.

Comment: The application is to maintain two arrays, one for registered and one for waitlisted students.  Each array stores the int id number of the students.  Your arrays should be declared within the main function (not globally outside all functions), and passed as arguments to any function that needs them. As indicated in the text,  in addition to having a variable to store the capacity of the array,  you will also need a variable to keep track of how many values are currently stored in each array.

Comment: The application should allow the user to do one of  5 things, until he/she wishes to exit:
        * register a student
        * unregister a student  
        * print list of registered students
        * print wait list

Make sure of that if a student wishes to be registered, but the class is full, the student is added to the waitlist, unless that list is also full.  You can use both class lists and waitlists of size 10 for this assignment, use a constant variable for the size.

Comment: In that case you can pass both the arrays to addtorear function. let the function decide which array to append based on the current index. You can use same logic for all of the 5 operations mentioned.

Comment: im sorry, but can you write this piece of code and show how it looks like if it not too much to ask? i know that you guys might think i am a lazy a$$ who just want to find easy way to get project done. but im totally lost here, i don't have any programming background at all. the worst part, im taking this course online. i just need this for my major's prerequisites.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is failing to identify full and empty condition for registration list and waiting list. I have made some modification in the below code. you can try below code snippet.

```
case 1:
            int len = sizeof(reg)/sizeof(reg[0]); // Get the length of reg list
            int waitlistLen = sizeof(waitlist)/sizeof(waitlist[0]); //get length of wait list
            if(maxCap > len)               // Check if reg list not full. Add to reg list
                addToRear(reg, howMany, maxCap);
            else if(maxCap > waitlistLen) // if reg list is full. Check if wait list is full or not
                addToRear(waitlist, howMany, maxCap);
            else                         // if both the list are full show user option menu and break.
                showOption();
            break;
```